# What I am doing wrong when trying to upload a file to a form using Python and Requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am learning web scraping with Python and I am trying to upload an image to a form for the first time. The website is aliseeks.com and I am not sure the URL I am trying to upload it to is the right one but it's the only one I found when inspecting the site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }

def search(image):
    s = requests.Session()

    result = requests.post(url='https://api.aliseeks.com/upload/image', files = image, headers = headers)
    
    print (result.text)
    
    
def main():
    file = {'upload_file': open('C:\\Users\\Ze\\Pictures\\Ajahn Brahm.jpg','rb')}
    search(file)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

**[{"exception":"MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present"}]**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for the [requests library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), specifically, the following part:

```
>>> url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

`files` is a dictionary with the field `'file'`. So maybe try replace `'upload_file'` with `'file'` instead?

Comment: Thank you so much! I had actually just done that right before I came here to check for replies. Now I am getting this:

[{"exception":"IllegalArgumentException","message":"Media type is null."}]

Comment: Maybe try: `file = {'file': ('<name of the file>', open('C:\\Users\\Ze\\Pictures\\Ajahn Brahm.jpg','rb'), 'image/jpeg' )}` It looks like from the docs that file can be a tuple instead of just a file descriptor. In that case, the first field is the name, the second field is the file descriptor, and the third field is the media type.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked!!! I love you forever!!